# Is this a valid way for testing a constructor

Tags: java, testing, junit, constructor

I recently started OOP (in Java) and was wondering if the following piece of code could validate if the constructor has been tested well, using a Junit test:

```
@Test
public void testConstructor() {
    MyClass c1 = new myClass("Text", 1);
    MyClass c2 = new myClass("Text", 1);
    assertEquals(c1,c2);
}

@Test
public void testConstructor2() {
    MyClass c1 = new myClass("Text", 1);
    MyClass c2 = new myClass("Text", 2);
    assertNotEquals(c1,c2);
}
```

Although it seems to be a valid check to me, I'm still a bit confused because most examples I've found about constructor testing use a `.get()` method.

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you testing for?

Comment: It feels a bit overkill to me.  You don't need to test every single method (and ctor), just enough to verify the class works correctly.  If you call a ctor and then verify some method that depends on that ctor being right, then I think that's enough testing for the ctor.

Comment: I was wondering if I can trust on the constructor being tested well enough.

Comment: @Surfboi: That completely depends.  What logic do you want to test?

Comment: One thing I would test explicitly is if you range test any variables and throw `IllegalArgumentException` (or any other exception).  Those you can test.  But normally you just test how the class behaves afterwords.  What you show above is really a test of the `equals()` method, and I would call it testing `equals()`.

Comment: Aren't you testing the `equals()` method here? Which is a perfectly valid and reasonable thing to do, but still, the distinction is important.

Comment: Also, note that Java conventions are to have class names camel cased (as you have) but starting with a capital letter: `MyClass` not `myClass`. Camel case that starts with a lowercase is conventionally for variable names. This is an almost ubiquitous standard, so you'd do well to get into the habit sooner rather than later. :)

Comment: @Slaks With this code I test for these situations obviously, but could I tell if the constructor is 100% working the way it's supposed to, using these two tests only? Or would you need additional tests in order to check for this?

Comment: @markspace  But then still if you want to test your `equals()` method all the way, you should have a condition where it's testing for a wrong kind object as well right? I know this is all overkill to do, but just want know these things for sure

Comment: @Surfboi I think you should sit down and think through what the purpose of testing really is. A comment isn't the appropriate medium to explain this, but a few pointers: confidence in code, pinpoint identification of problems, complexity vs. estimated likelihood of error, time spent writing tests vs. time saved by having tests. We are doing testing for a practical purpose, not just to have tests, and you need to be clear what you want to get out of it before you start.

Comment: @biziclop I appreciate your advice and also understand what you try to tell me. This question made me confused as well, it was a question in my OOP exam, when the answers get posted I just get to know if it was answer a,b,c or d and I wanted to clarify it, so therefore the post.

Comment: @Surfboi Ah, that explains a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

If your constructor is doing really trivial things (like just setting fields), then you don't need to unit test it specifically. You won't gain much confidence in your code (since you probably had a lot anyway — it wasn't doing much that it could get wrong), and other tests that instantiate and use objects will inherently test that you didn't make trivial mistakes.

If your constructor is doing something complicated, you may be better off spinning that logic into a package-private static method and then unit testing that method by itself. If that's not reasonable (for instance, the logic sets multiple fields), then your unit tests should test the specific state you expect:

```
MyClass object = MyClass("Text", 1);
assertEquals("someComplicatedValue", object.getSomeField());
```

You shouldn't just test for object equality, since that doesn't tell you whether the fields are *right*, just that they're the same given identical input.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not put any logic in constructor except some variable initialization. Also with Dependency Injection need to keep those clean. Equals will call the equals method, so the above would not be a fare test of creation. In this case only white box testing works, like giving invalid params to constructor and such, since you have to ask what could go wrong ...